# What is the http verb kinesis firehose use when targeting a http endpoint?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis

I am reading this doc https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/stream-data-to-an-http-endpoint-with-amazon-kinesis-data-firehose/ to see how kinesis firebose connects to a http endpoint.

but it doesn't mention what http verb it uses to put data to the target endpoint. Is it put or post? Can I configure it?

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear what verb is that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tested that using lambda and api gateway. The logs show its **POST**:

```
        "http": {
            "method": "POST",
            "path": "/default/delete",
            "protocol": "HTTP/1.1",
            "sourceIp": "3.26.56.41",
            "userAgent": "Amazon Kinesis Data Firehose Agent/1.0"
        },
```

Comment: Thanks for checking it. How can I change it to PUT?

Comment: @JoeyYiZhao No problem.I don't think you can.